# Can I write a Conan recipe to download and install a package from the web?

Tags: conan

We just started using conan, so I'm still new. One of our dependent libs doesn't have a conan recipe (it's just a cmake-based project on github).
Can I write my own local recipe to download it from github and build it so I can add it to my dependencies like any other conan project?

Comment: Yes. That is what conan is mostly for. Download From repo. Then build Then publish.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? Creating a recipe for a third-party package without having the source local? Would love to see an example.

Comment: [Checkout code](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.53/creating_packages/external_repo.html). [Build step](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.43/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html)

Comment: Thanks! That first one makes the light go on for me. 
Make it an answer so I can accept it, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First checkout the code. You can either do that by using the git tools or run command.

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

class HelloConan(ConanFile):

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone https://github.com/conan-io/hello.git")
    #or using git tools
        git = tools.Git(folder="hello")
        git.clone("https://github.com/conan-io/hello.git", "master")
```

Then build it as you normally would with either cmake tools or run command

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class ExampleConan(ConanFile):
    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        self.run('cmake "%s" %s' % (self.source_folder, cmake.command_line))
        self.run('cmake --build . %s' % cmake.build_config)
        self.run('cmake --build . --target install')
        cmake = CMake(self)

    #Using cmake tools
        build_folder=self.build_folder)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        cmake.test() # Build the "RUN_TESTS" or "test" target
        cmake.install()
```

For my information look at the documentation for

[Creating a new conanfile.py](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.53/reference/commands/creator/new.html)

[Checkoing out the code](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.53/creating_packages/external_repo.html)

[Building using cmake](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.43/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html)

Comment: The tools used in this example are a bit outdated, and have been superseded by more modern ones in ``from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMakeDeps, CMake``. The ``conan new hello/0.1 -m=cmake_lib`` will give a working template for a "hello world" example library.

Comment: @drodri Can you please answer based on the latest changes

Comment: For a full working recipe that downloads existing code from another repo, the example and instructions in https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/creating_packages/handle_sources_in_packages.html will work. But in practice, if it your own library and you own the repo, it is better to just put a conanfile.py in the same repo, so it is synced with the code. In that case the example and code in https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/creating_packages/create_your_first_package.html will cover it.